# How to do http post with the results/data you get from the complete function in papaparse?

Tags: angular, papaparse

I am basically getting the following error

```
Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
```

My codes are the following:

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient, private papa: PapaParseService) {}
  results:any;
  createOrders(csvData) {
    this.http.post(environment.ordersUrl, {'order': csvData})
    .toPromise().then((data)=> console.log(data));
  }
  handleFileSelect(evt) {
    let file = evt.target.files[0];
    this.papa.parse(file, {
      header: true,
      dynamicTyping: true,
      complete: function(csvOrders) {
        this.http.post(environment.ordersUrl, {'order': csvOrders.data}).subscribe();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a scope/binding problem - `this` inside the function you're passing as `complete` is **not** the `AppComponent` instance. Use arrow functions.

Comment: Thank you!! I used the fat arrow approach and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete function you are calling has a different scope inside of it therefore different `this`.

You could use either a fat arrow function:

```
complete: csvOrders => {
    ...
 }
```

Or bind `this` to the function:

```
complete: function(csvOrders) {
  ...
}.bind(this)
```